# What is the difference between ArcGIS and MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview, arcgis

Is there any difference between ArcGIS and MKMapView?

I want to work on custom annotation map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are used to show the maps and locations on the iPhone app..

However MKMapView comes with iPhone SDK, and uses the google services for maps.

In case of ArcGIS, it is also used  navigate maps, collect and report data, and perform GIS analysis, but in this case, the service are provided by the ESRI

For More Information: [Does ESRI consider Google and Microsoft to be competitors?](http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=2A8E2713-1422-2418-7F20BB7C186B5B83&questionId=2631)